# Upper bound for chromatic number related to number of edges

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Prove that in any simple, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$, the chromatic number $χ(G)≤  \sqrt{2m} +1$, where $m=|E|$

Comment: Related: [edges and chromatic number inequality](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167258/edges-and-chromatic-number-inequality). A kind of dual, since a lower bound on number of edges is there expressed in terms of the chromatic number.  I did not look carefully, but these might be equivalent propositions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $\chi(G)=k$. Take a $k$-coloring of $G$; it divides $V$ into $k$ color classes, say $V_1,\ldots,V_k$. For each pair of distinct $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$ there must be at least one edge between $V_i$ and $V_j$; why? How many edges does that guarantee at a minimum?

Comment: We may take as known, from the linked Question above, that there are at least $\binom{k}{2}$ edges.  The task is then to "solve" that inequality to get the desired upper bound on chromatic number $k$ in terms of number of edges $m$.