# How to show that for any graph $G=(V, E)$, we have $|E|\ge$ $\chi(G) \choose 2$?

Tags: graph-theory

Question :

> Prove that for any graph $G=(V, E)$, we have $|E|\ge$ $\chi(G) \choose
>  2$

My reasoning is as follows:
First, We take the set $(x, y)$ as an edge, and we can have $|V|$ sets of 2 elements, which means $|E|\ge$ $|V|\choose 2$.
Second, we know that $|V|\ge \chi(G)\ge1$, so either $|V|\choose 2$=$\chi(G)\choose 2$, or $|V|\choose 2$ $\ge$ $\chi(G)\choose 2$, thus proved.

Would this be viable as a proof ?, it seems lacking.

Comment: Is $X(G)$ supposed to be $\chi(G)$? If not, can you define it?

Comment: Your first step is wrong. You cannot prove that every set on $n$ nodes has at least $\binom{n}{2}$ edges —  this is simply not true.

Comment: As for a valid proof: see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167258/edges-and-chromatic-number-inequality).